# Get Same data in different row in to a same row

Tags: sql

I have a table with columns

```
Account number (number)
Account  Status(Number)
Datetime(text)
```

some accounts are repeating with same time stamp

I need to get the account status of repeating data of the same account with same timestamp to same row as new column (new Account Status)

```
Account_Number    Account Status       Timestamp
7856277             5                  9155070519
4527882             5                  1045225522
7856277             1                  9155070519
```

I want to

```
Account_Number    Account Status       Timestamp   new account Status
7856277             5                  9155070519    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to join the table with itself, using the account number as the linked column. Consider the query below (where `o` is the older record and `n` is the newer one)

```
SELECT o.account_number, o.account_status, n.timestamp, n.account_status "new account status"
FROM table o join table n on (o.account_number = n.account_number)
WHERE n.timestamp>o.timestamp
```

Comment: The timestamps are the same.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, there is no "new" or "old" unless a column specifies the ordering.  You don't seem to have such a column.

But you can use aggregation to get the results on a single row:

```
select Account_Number, Timestamp,
       min(AccountStatus) as status_min,
       max(AccountStatus) as status_max
from t
group by Account_Number, Timestamp
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a self join:

```
SELECT 
  t.account_number, t.account_status, t.timestamp, 
  tt.account_status new_account_status
FROM tablename t INNER JOIN tablename tt 
ON 
  tt.account_number = t.account_number AND 
  tt.timestamp = t.timestamp AND 
  tt.account_status < t.account_status
```